# Displaying both on and off states of flip toggle switch using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, slider

I want to be able to display both On and Off section of the flip toggle switch. A demo code which works for older versions of jquery is:

```
               <div data-role="fieldcontain"> 
                <label for="slider">Flip switch:</label> 
                <select name="slider" id="my-slider" data-role="slider"> 
                <option value="off">Browse</option> 
                <option value="on">Post</option> 
                </select> 
               </div>
```

which renders as :
[image]

but in my code where i use jquery-1.9.1.min.js and jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js, the same code renders as[image]

how can i keep using the same .js files but make the switch look like the previous image?
I could change the version of .js files i am using but that would mess other elements on the page.